# Using Bit Torrent under openDNS content filtering

Tags: bittorrent

My University has openDNS content filtering over it's WiFi network, so WhatsApp, Facebook app and obviously Torrent are blocked. Folks use Psiphon to bypass these, but this doesn't work for torrent. Any torrent client doesn't download any file under the VPN. I don't know anything, so please explain if and how Tor could be useful here. Also, what would I need to do to download torrent files using BitTorrent?

Comment: Using a VPN or a seedbox would be a more appropriate solution for bittorrenting, than Tor

Comment: Psiphon is a VPN service. Doesn't work. Bit torrent client doesn't show any connection, with the yellow button and 0 K/s U/D speed.

Comment: Read that as using a VPN that is not Psiphon and is designed to work with Bittorrent.

Comment: Okay sure. Any open source suggestions you have in mind?

Comment: It's services you most likely need to pay for. Have a look at [/r/VPN/](https://www.reddit.com/r/VPN/)